# Ошибка в вычислении python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему питон считает именно так?

```
lst=['q', '15', 'G', '9', 'Z', '16', 'R', '17', 'a', '14',
     'p', '3', 'c', '9', 'o', '1', 'G', '10', 'Q', '4']
lst2 = ''
for i in lst[:len(lst)-1:2]:
    print(lst[lst.index(i) + 1])
    y = int(lst[lst.index(i) + 1])
    lst2 += i * y
print(lst2)
```

Вывод:

```
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqGGGGGGGGGZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppccccccccco**GGGGGGGGG**QQQQ
```

Почему переменная "y" становится равным 9 вместо 10?

Comment: q 15
G 9
Z 16
R 17
a 14
p 3
c 9
o 1
**G 9**
Q 4
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqGGGGGGGGGZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppcccccccccoGGGGGGGGGQQQQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас два раза 'G' в списке встречается, `index` находит первое включение.